# Return a value from a function in Kotlin

Tags: android, function, kotlin, variables, return

I'm just learning Kotlin, I have learnt series of lessons about functions and variables, but find it difficult to understand Return a value from a function lesson.

Comment: Can't really tell you what information is missing from the lesson without you telling us or telling us which lessons you're taking so we can look at them.

Answer (score 0):

function with no params and no return type

```
fun sampleFunction(){
        
}
```

function with params and no return type

```
fun sampleFunction(value:Int){

}
```

function with params and Integer return type

```
fun sampleFunction(value:Int):Int{ 
    return value+1
}
```

function with variable arguments params and no return type

```
fun sampleFunction(vararg values:Int){ 
values.forEach {value-> /*value is each variable arguments*/ } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the lesson in this link teaches: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-functions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-functions#2

Comment: i have given example of what is mentioned in the codelab

Comment: alright, i will try it out. it's just that, i'm next to a novice. kotlin is my first programming language to learn.